# How to check if there is an edge between nodes of a graph in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to add edge to some nodes, there may be an edge between them already https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.addedge.html however this function only adds if there is none, otherwise it gives error. So how can i check before. Thanks

Comment: [`findedge`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.findedge.html)?

Comment: yes i found that command also, thank you. Though it just is very slow, i consider coding it using adjecancy matrix

Comment: Do you want to know if there is an edge or a path? If you already have an adjacency matrix, finding an edge is as simple as checking the matrix entry. Are you asking how to construct an adjacency matrix?